# What does Object mean in this context and why is it defined as such?

Tags: java, object, linked-list

Currently, I'm learning how to program in Java, and I'm currently attempting to implement a basic Linked List to further my understanding of how the language differs from C++ that I learned in school. Right now, I'm trying to understand why the word "Object" here is used and what it means.

```
private class ListNode {
    private Object data;
    private ListNode next;
}
```

I understand that next is of the type ListNode, which I declared, but I'm not sure what the Object type is. Is it found in a library of Java, or is it a default type? I've been researching this and all I've found are pages about primitive data types and such.

Comment: I googled "java object". Here are my findings: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+object&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Comment: consult [the API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining `Object` class, which can be answered by an easy search on a SEO.

Comment: You should follow a tutorial. Start with [the official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Object is a class itself? Oh okay. My apologies everyone. I'll definitely look into. Sorry if I asked a bad question on here.

Comment: @JackyHo check the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in help guide for future questions in the site :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Java API documentation on Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

All objects inherit from `Object` implicitly. So your `ListNode` class is equivalent to:

```
private class ListNode extends Object {
    private Object data;
    private ListNode next;
}
```

Methods like toString() are inherited from the Object parent class.

In your specific case, you are using the Object type because you don't know what kind of data your list will hold, and since all classes are Objects that's the "catch-all" type. There's a better way to handle this scenario in Java, called [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), but you're probably not quite to that point yet. Something to keep in mind for the future.